# Understanding negation in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Given the following knowledge base:

```
car(X) :- ferrari(X).
car(X) :- bmw(X).
car(X) :- ford(X).

ferrari(f).
ferrari(y).
bmw(b).
ford(a).
```

Why is it that these two (seemingly identical) rules produce completely different results when I query them?

```
-- Rule one (returns all the cards except ford
loves(lana,X) :- \+ ford(X), car(X).

-- Rule two (returns nothing, just fails)
loves(lana,X) :- car(X), \+ ford(X).
```

Comment: rules do not "return ... etc.", queries do. you don't show the query in each case.

Comment: Just the query `loves(lana,X`).`

Comment: add it to the question please.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have your examples backwards, as:

```
?- car(X), \+ ford(X).
X = f ;
X = y ;
X = b ;
false.

?- \+ ford(X), car(X).
false.
```

The problem here is simply that negation-as-failure means that negation can never establish a binding. The way Prolog's negation works, it tries to prove the query, and then the outcome of that (success or failure) gets inverted. Because the success is inverted into failure, no bindings are established.

In the first query, Prolog begins by searching for a car(X). Once it has that binding, it tries to prove that X is a ford. If X is a ford, then the query fails; otherwise, the query succeeds. So Prolog found f, and f is a car, and ford(f) fails, so the query succeeds. You ask it for some more solutions and eventually it locates car(a) and asks ford(a), which succeeds, so that query fails and X=a never makes it back to the user.

In the second case, Prolog begins by trying to find a ford(X). This succeeds in establishing X=a, so the negation inverts the sense of that and we fail. Prolog has nowhere else to back up to, so the query simply fails. There is nothing else for it to try. As @WillNess points out, either there is a ford(X) or there is not.

In other words, in the first query, you are generating all the cars and then asking if *a specific car* is a ford. In the second query, you are generating all the *fords*, and then failing the query as `ford(X)` will never generate a not-ford.

Comment: the slogan that I always have in  mind is, "Prolog's 'not' means, 'can't prove' ". It helps somehow. :)

Comment: so, I think, in `\+ford(X), car(X)`, `\+ford(X)` tries to prove `ford(X)`, proves it,  then fails full stop. When a goal fails a backtracking happens to the one goal *before* it (i.e. *before* `\+ford(X)`) but here there aren't any goals to retry *before* the `\+ford(X)`. And if they were, such that `X` would remain unbound, `\+ford(X)` would fail them again, and again.

Comment: (contd.) "... fail them again, and again" ... with the *same* `X=a` binding. i.e. it doesn't retry `ford(X)` after finding `X=a`, and if there were more `ford` facts, they wouldn't have been *tried*. in effect, it is as if it were defined as `not(X):- X, !, fail`. --- another way to read it, I think, is that `\+ford(X)` with free `X` means "there does not exist any `X` such that `ford(X)` holds". so there's no retrying there, either it exists, or it doesn't. :)

Comment: @WillNess I think your comments are so useful you should make them an answer!

Comment: K. :) and thanks. It is easy to get lost in negation's operational goings on. But then I say to myself: "can't prove that..." and it becomes clearer again.

Answer (score 1):

A slogan that I always have in mind is, "Prolog's *'not'* means, *'can't prove'* ". It helps somehow.

In the query `\+ford(X), car(X)`, the first goal `\+ford(X)` tries to prove `ford(X)`, proves it, and thus fails.

When a goal fails a backtracking happens to the one goal before it (i.e. before `\+ford(X)`) but here there aren't any goals before `\+ford(X)`, in the query. Nothing to retry, the failure is final.

In effect, it is as if it were defined as `\+(X) :- X, !, fail`.

Another way to read it, I think, is that `\+ford(X)` with the free `X` means *"there does not exist any `X` such that `ford(X)` holds"*. Clearly, that's not true. Such `X` does exist: it is `X=a`.